# JQueryUI absolutely not working with my aspx page

Tags: asp.net, jquery-ui

Here's a part of my aspx page:

```
<span id="drag">This can be dragged </span>
<input id="save" type="button" value="Save" />
<div id="dialog">
</div>

<script src="Scripts/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="Scripts/jquery-ui-1.9.0.custom.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="Scripts/ui.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

And here's my ui.js file:

```
$('#save').click(function ()
{
  $('#dialog').dialog();
});

$(document).ready(function ()
{
  $('#drag').draggable();
});
```

And I've linked the css file in my masterpage :

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="CSS\ui-lightness\jquery-ui-1.8.24.custom.css">
```

If I try this in a plain html file I get both draggable and dialog functionalities to work but neither function works when I try it in my aspx page.Is there a special consideration with ASP.NET?

Comment: Are you getting any errors in the console of your browser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably loading 2 times the jquery library.

remove this resource :

Comment: Yes, you were absolutely right about loading the jquery lib. At the bottom of my master page, I'd left library imports from previous tries  and forgot to remove them. So yes, I was two times importing the jquery library.

Answer (score 1):

What does the rendered HTML look like?
Maybe you have a problem with rendered **ID** of your controls
[**Here**](http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/2009/Nov/07/ClientIDMode-in-ASPNET-40)'s an article about clientId Mode

ClientIDMode can take the following four possible values

- **AutoID** - ASP.NET generate IDs as it does in v3.5 and earlier
  versions.
- **Static** - ASP.NET use exactly the same ID given to the
  server control for its client-side ID.
- **Predictable** - ASP.NET try to
  generate IDs that are guessable from looking at the structure of the
  page.
- **Inherit** - ASP.NET generate a client-side ID for the page or
  control using the same ClientIDMode as its parent. i.e. the client ID
  gets inherited from the parent control.

This one can be set in the *control* directly, in the *page* or in the *webConfig* file.

Answer (score 1):

are all the files being downloaded? did you check this with fiddler, firebug or developer tools?

Answer (score 0):

If you are not getting any error in browser's console then u should use "jQuery" instead of "$" symbol